# Ubuntu 22.04 / Modify Power Saver Behavior (Do Not Dim Screen)

Tags: display, 22.04, power-management, brightness, gnome-power-manager

First of all, I think it's really cool that Ubuntu 22.04 (I upgraded from 20.04, the last LTS version) now has the ability to switch between different profiles. Depending on what I do, I have times when my machine, calculation-wise is basically in idle, but I would like the screen to not go dim, even when I don't give any input. So accordingly, I've deselected "dim screen" and gone "Blank screen: never". But I've noticed that that behavior is ignored when "Power Saver" is selected. I would like the computer to save power while I am only using the display basically, but the fact that the screen goes dim every other minute and I have to move the mouse is more than a little annoying.
I am solving chess puzzles, for anyone wondering :)

Any ideas? Can I modify the behavior of the power saver somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 100`

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/utle2w/ubuntu_2204_is_there_a_way_to_disable_screen/