# Ubuntu 22.04 unwanted auto dim, 'Automatic Brightness' doesn't exists in power settings

Tags: power-management, screen, brightness

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my PC. I am experiencing some weird dimming behavior:

- If I present a *white image* on my screen, the screen gets *brighter*
- If I present a *black image* on my screen, the screen gets *darker*

I saw many posts recommending that I turn off 'Automatic Brightness' in the power setting, however this option does not exists for me.

It might be worth mentioning that this only occurs on one of my two monitors (the one connected to my graphics card).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my new installation of 22.04.1 is doing this on my new 2nd hand ASUS TUF laptop. even though I have dim screen disabled in power settings. it does it on a short timer. and when plugged into power supply. I have also disabled automatic power saving in power settings. and screen blank never in power settings.

Comment: see here... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405733/ubuntu-22-04-modify-power-saver-behavior-do-not-dim-screen

I did have power on power saver in power settings.